# jquery button don't align properly in chrome

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-chrome

I'm trying to dinamically add a button to an input.

It's working with IE9 but I have position problems with chrome 15.0.874.121 m, sometimes applying zoom to chrome the button align properly

Here is a sample http://jsbin.com/etacap/latest

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by modifiying your .deleteButton class, you can reach something decent.

```
.deleteButton{
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  top:3px; /*or 16%*/
}
```

yet, there is still a 2 pixels difference T_T. Ideally it would be 4px for chrome, and 2 for ie.

**EDIT:** alternatively you could do something like this:

```
...
myButton.height(myText.height()+2);
var top = $.browser.webkit ? '4px' : '2px';
myButton.css('top', top);
```

Comment: Do you know how is jquery calculating the input height?

Comment: nope, I didn't investigate that part. I prefer not to enter deeply in these actively developed plugins, as they are subject to change. So a "quick and dirty" patch like this is easier to maintain/remove. Of course I could try to participate to jquery-ui itself, but I don't I have talent enough to participate (except for the occasional bug hunting), and overall I miss time to really help the team.

Answer (score 0):

could you design for chrome such that it renders correctly in chrome and then use IE conditional comments to render IE specific styles